# how to add loader in angularjs when html table bind

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html table

```
<body ng-app>    
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="InboxMailCtrl">                             
        <table>    
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="" ng-click="ViewEmailDetails(CU.InboxMailID)">{{CU.Reciever}}</a></td>
                    <td class="text-right mail-date">{{CU.time}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is my angularjs code for binding the html table

```
var InboxMailCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    if (loginuserid != null) {
        BindInboxList();
    }

    function BindInboxList(Data) {
        var UserEmail = sessionStorage.getItem("loginUserID");
        var obj = {
            data: UserEmail
        }

        $http({
            url: "MailRoute/getDataForMail",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: obj,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {        
        }).error(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
};
```

Every thing is working fine. My problem is that I want to add a loader when datatable is loading. Actually lots of data is binding so I want to add a loader. `BindInboxList()` is a function in angularjs for binding the html table. How to do this? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need any loaders?
`ng-bind` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind should do the trick.

Comment: this link has no concept about loader